# Sql Injection and no priviliges to write files

Tags: sql-injection

I have a sql injection in my site and im using sqlmap but when i try --os-shell it says cannot write file due to permissions . now is it impossible to write a file to the server?

Comment: Please supply some more information: What DBMS is the target? Does the corresponding user have file permissions at all?

Comment: You need to escalate privilige to write file. [escalate privilige](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/31/how-to-escalate-privileges-in-mysql/)

Comment: When it is really your website, you should be focusing on how to close the SQL injection, not on how to further exploit it. Or do you try to break the security of a specific system you do not own? In that case your question would be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [escalate privilige](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/31/how-to-escalate-privileges-in-mysql/) to write file.

Comment: You can only change privileges if you already have the *GRANT OPTION* privilege.

Comment: the site in ours but im getting beyond work to test what hacker can do..

Comment: the dbms is mysql and im using php ..currently no permission to write files using method INTO OUTFILE

Comment: I suppose that you successfully exploitat an SQL injection vulnerability and you gain access to the database. Then you need to test if you can escalate priviliges : check this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/inquis/advanced-sql-injection-to-operating-system-full-control-slides) (slide 55) from BlackHat Con.

Comment: @seco What granted privileges does `SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User=CURRENT_USER()` return when you login with that user?

Comment: yes i want escalate priviliges but the slides you share for windows and my server is linux

Comment: There is no specific way to esclate priviliges, You need to gather all kind of information about the target (software version, OS version, file permissions ..etc) and [look](http://www.exploit-db.com) for exploits to esclate priviliges and gain further access.
For example : If you find out that the version of your DBMS is MySQL 4.x/5.0 you can use this [exploit](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/1518/)